# Make views intercept taps but not scroll events

Tags: android

My problem is that I can't find a way where I intercept taps without blocking the propagation of other events, such as scroll, to the views bellow it.

I'm using a custom view to handle the tap events:

```
public class TapableImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
    ...
    public void setOnTapListener(OnTapListener onTapListener){
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
                onTapListener.onTap(TapableImageView.this);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        if(mDetector != null)
            return !mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        private long startClickTime;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                startClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                yourview.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

            } else  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                yourview.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startClickTime < ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()) {

                    // Touch was a simple tap
                    return true;

                } else {

                    // Touch was a not a simple tap.
                    return false;

                }

            }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

check if the time between the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events is lower or higher than the value given by `ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()`

Comment: How could I propagate the scroll events from the else block to the other views?

Comment: the touch listener is added to a specific view...not sure what do u mean by propagate?

Comment: if `onTouch` returns true the event is handled by the view right? When that happens, the views bellow it are not not receiving any other touch events. I want that in the case that is not a single tap, the other views bellow it receive the touch events.

Comment: you can write `yourview.dispatchTouchEvent(event);`' in the else block to trigger the event

Comment: Ok, your solution kind of worked. I propagated the events to the desired view on ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE, and just use the ACTION_UP to check if it was really a tap. If you edit it I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You must return false to indicate that the event is not consumed

Comment: Return false allows the scrolling, but the tap events are not recognized.

Comment: even if you do stuff before to return false?

Comment: Yes, the tap event is just intercepted when `dispatchTouchEvent` returns true.

Comment: yeah but before `dispatchTouchEvent` returns true or false you can do what you want. You have already overriden `dispatchTouchEvent` method

Comment: Yes, but for some reason the `GestureDetectorCompat` is not dispatching the taps when returning `dispatchTouchEvent` returns false.

Comment: You don't need that `GestureDetectorCompat` propagate Tap. You can do what you want without propagate Tap event, then returning false and enjoing propagation of other events like Scroll. Nor?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong and you need to return `false` into `onSingleTapUp` ?